# how to filter a table using row value=NULL in laravel controller

Tags: mysql, laravel

```
   public function complaint_pending(){

    $complaints = Complaint::whereNull('answear')->get();

    return view('admin.complaint.panding',compact('complaints'));

   }
```

I want to show Complaint all data which answer row is NULL

My DB pic is below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2dKl.jpg)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try the following code

```
public function complaint_pending(){

    $complaints = Complaint::where('answear',NULL)->get();

    return view('admin.complaint.panding',compact('complaints'));

}
```

Comment: public function complaint_pending(){
    
    $complaints = Complaint::where('answear', NULL)->get();
    
    return view('admin.complaint.panding',compact('complaints'));
    }

Comment: I will accept plz edit first 'NULL' to NULL

Comment: because i can't edit that

Answer (score 0):

you have type error in function.

change **answear** to **answer** in complaint_pending method.

Comment: i al ready edit that. Thank you

Comment: please add score for my answer

Comment: i need more reputation for vote

Answer (score -2):

That's not work but it's work perfectly ...

```
  public function complaint_pending(){
    
    $complaints = Complaint::where('answear', NULL)->get();
    
    return view('admin.complaint.panding',compact('complaints'));
    }
```